# ElasticSearch install Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, elasticsearch

I have installed the latest version on elasticsearch on my raspberry pi by following (**I am not sure if elasticsearch is even running correctly** )

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html

When I do curl it asks me for password

[image]

Here is service status of my elasticsearch

[image]

I even disable elasticsearch security in yaml file .

```
#http.enabled: false

xpack.security.enabled: false
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: false
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: false
```

When I did restart of elasticsearch it still asks me for password . IS there a way to disable authentication where I can access elasticsearch with curl directly ?

Below is my elasticsearch service status

[image]

Below is process

[image]

Comment: Reset and password and use new one in `curl`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-password-reset.html

Comment: @RomeoNinov He doesn't want to use a password at all.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned already you can change it by following [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-password-reset.html) procedure.

As far as I know you can't have user w/o password so the user must set the password in script (or whatever it use this `curl` command)